# How to set UIButton keep selected/highlighted until match a condition?

Tags: iphone

how can i do that? i want my UIButton remain selected until have make certain condition

Answer (score 0):

In the IBAction  set the

```
[UIButton  setSelected:YES]
```

And check it with `isSelected:YES`

When needing to change `setSelected:NO`